# Browser extension that can play YouTube videos faster than x2

Tags: video, youtube, productivity

I am looking for a browser extension that can play YouTube videos faster than x2 in the browser, and if possible, work with Google Chrome and Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

You could use MySpeed (a paid product - *I'm not affiliated with it in any way*). It integrates automatically with all browsers, although you would have to initially install it via a windows installer.

This will then do EXACTLY what you've asked for:

This will:

- play YouTube videos,
- faster than x2,
- in the browser, and
- work with Google Chrome and Windows 7

Answer (score 2):

Not an extension, but a cheap workaround for Chrome/Firefox/Brave/Opera/Vivaldi/etc that will work with *any* HTML5 video or audio on any page (unless it's inside an `iframe`):

1. Right-click anywhere on the page and pick <kbd>Inspect</kbd>.
2. In the devtools window that opens go to `Console`, adjust and paste the script below, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
document.querySelectorAll('video,audio').forEach(m => {
    m.playbackRate = 2.5;
    m.play();
})
```

> NOTE: set your own desired `playbackRate`

This will play *all* the HTML5 videos and audios on the page at 2.5x speed. Adjust to your taste.

## 2.5x Browser Bookmarklet

By placing a bookmarklet in your browser Bookmarks bar you can run the snippet above with a single click without the need to open devtools.

- [Bookmarklet Video/Audio at 2.5x speed](https://www.taosdev.com/bookmarklet-devkit/#EQChEoAIF4D5IN4B0B2l2QCYHsDGBXAWwFMUAXAOgEd9iAnATwGViAbY3M7OgQVdZAByAG4BLTMWwAaAIb5Mo7IPAUAZtwCiM3AAsQhGPGRoMpwhQAOrGQwBG2gNYAlGWWIxIAJgoBWANyopmaW1gwQASboAL7gqDHhwEA)

***Usage***: in the editor page that opens drag the **Drag me..** link to your browser's Bookmarks bar. While on a page containing HTML5 video/audio such as youtube or any other site click the corresponding bookmarklet.