# Is there any free software that allow you to control video playback speed

Tags: windows, video

Is there any software that allow you to control video playback speed, similar to ["Enounce MySpeed"](http://www.enounce.com/myspeed)?

Example: I would like to watch online tutorials at e.g. 2x speed.

I'm not interested in the HTML 5 workaround that you can enable on YouTube, since I would like to be able to watch videos from any other website.

I also know about the combination of DownloadHelper and VLC that allow similar functionality but I want one app that can do it all in one.

*I tried the trial of Enounce MySpeed but it doesn't work on windows 8*

**PLEASE NOTE (before you comment):**
Everyone so far has suggested that I clearly specify I need online software. I DO NOT NEED ONLINE SOFTWARE. What I need is a **local executable** that allow me to change the playback speed of **BOTH online & offline videos**.

1) Please don't suggest online solutions (ie. a html plugin/html5 viewing etc because **I'm not looking for this**) 
2) Please don't attempt to rewrite my question again (I clearly mean **EXACTLY** what I asked)

Comment: Related: [Browser extension that can play YouTube videos faster than x2](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/3314/903)

Comment: almost related, but I'm not looking for a plugin, I'm looking for an application.

Comment: @z0mbi3: MySpeed Premier v5.4.5 **works on windows 8.1** x64 (I'm using the trial now). But you have severe misunderstandings about it. You say you're looking for a *single app* that will integrate into "absolutely any video you play," local or streaming, like MySpeed. The Premier version will only play local files in one of of 3 flash video players Enounce supports. And it will **only play FLV and MP4 files.**. This excludes such common formats as DivX and XviD (AVI), Bluray Discs, and DVDs, and is really only useful for flash videos you've downloaded previously, with other software.

Comment: You should clearly specify that you need online software.

Comment: I do not clearly specify I need online software ... Because I don't clearly need online software .... I need a local exe application, that allow you to view both online and offline content, while allowing you to adjust speed.

Comment: Thanks  @TwoSheds. So far you are the only one who gets what I'm asking for, although I do feel I understand MySpeed quite well. To give a real example of what I am using it for ... If I watch online tutorials on youtube and PluralSight, I can easily watch it at 2x normal speed. Similarly, I can also use it offline on any tutorial that I have previously downloaded. This is my main usage. Any software that can do this will be perfect for me (other suggestions still welcome). Since TwoSheds claims to have it working on Win 8.1, I will buy it and ask support to help me get it working.

Comment: @z0mbi3: Sorry if I sounded harsh in my original response. What I thought you were misapprehending was citing MySpeed as an example of software that could handle any video, while it can really only use two video formats. MP4 is becoming fairly common because it plays on other media devices (phones/roku/TVs/etc), so I suppose there are fairly good odds that it will cover anything you find. If you do encounter something like an AVI or MKV that you want to view, there are many video converters that should be very easy to find and use.

Comment: @z0mbi3: Also, since the software is $100 (very expensive for a relatively simple media player), I would suggest getting the free 7 day trial and testing your compatibility with that. It would be a shame to find out late that you have some kind of rare device incompatibility, or a corrupted windows platform that would require reinstalling the OS.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @TwoSheds. Your anwers seem the best. Unfortunately MySpeed is very expensive and it seems to me that currently there are no other alternatives. I am aware of all the other solutions mentioned on here (downloading & conversion / html5 settings / download & using viewers that support custom playback speed) but none of these options are really feasible when trying to watch a 1hr tutorial at 2x speed (both on- and offline) when it is spread over 20 video fragments.

Answer (score 4):

KMPlayer right click on screen>playback>fast or shift+Num +

VLC also has this feature it is under playback>speed>faster fine (which increments speed in .1 increments or playback>speed>faster which increments playback speed my version is VLC portable 2.0.1

i use both to study for my ccna to speed up videos

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, however I am looking for an online video solution (such as myspeed - which unfortunately don't work on Win8). It integrates into abosolutely any video you play, with a speed control popping up whenever you watch any video - online / offline.

Comment: @z0mbi3 I have rewritten your question (especially the title) because you only mentioned 'online' as an adjective in your text - no wonder people read over that. Next time please make your question clearer.

Comment: @JanDoggen, not sure why you would do that!???? You clearly don't get my question, so don't even try to interpret it. I meant exactly what I asked. This is NOT ONLY for online videos - it's for ANY videos. Go see what MySpeed does before you try to interpret my question. Further, I have given an example ... it's far from the only use case. Please don't go around interpreting people's questions to your thinking. The reason there is no answer is because there is no product other than MySpeed that can do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [GOM Player](https://www.gomlab.com/) as it's the only player I know, where speed can be set in range 0.1x to 4x.
In other players it is limited by 2x.